# Set content-type to XHTML in static files

Tags: express

I want to have a route for my static files:

```
// server.js
app.use('/', require('./routes/ui/templates'));
```

The thing is that I cannot change the content-type from html->xhtml. Here's my route:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// Path configs
const pathRoot = __dirname
const pathPublic = pathRoot + "/../../public/" 

router.use('/', express.static(pathPublic));

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(pathPublic)
    res.sendFile('index.html', {root: pathRoot});
})

router.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.type('application/xhtml+xml');
    next();
})

module.exports = router;
```

Note that for some reason, if I don't add the `router.use(...)` 
my index file is not served at all. From what I understand, the middleware I've
written should be last as I am trying to capture the response and modify it.
Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to manage the `Content-Type` for specific types of files sent by `express.static()`, you can use the `setHeaders` option like this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public"), {
    setHeaders: function(res, path, stat) {
        // if file is a .xml file, then set content-type
        if (path.endsWith(".xml")) {
            res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/xhtml+xml");
        }
    }
}));
```

Some other things you may also be asking about:

1. Once your `express.static()` route matches a file, no further routing is done.  The response is sent and none of the route handlers that follow will be called.  So, you can't impact the content-type elsewhere with later routes.
2. If the request route path is `/`, then `express.static()` will look for an `index.html` file in the `pathPublic` you're passing it.  If it finds it, it will send that and no further routing will happen.
3. `res.type()` does not do what you seem to be trying to use it for.  You pass it a file extension and it sets the content-type according to a mime lookup for that file extension.  As you can see in my code example above, you can set the content type yourself with `res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/xhtml+xml")`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/xhtml+xml');`